# Backwards typing effect

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to get a backwards typing effect with my code. So the `<P>` will say "Coming Soon" then type backwards. Then type forwards into "SeaDogs.com.eu.as"

This is what I have so far, for some reason it type coming soon backwards twice??? Which is my first hurtle I'm trying to overcome. And trying to delay it so it shows the word "Coming soon" for a few seconds.

```js
var str = 'Coming Soon';
var remove = false;
var i = str.length;
var isTag;
var text;

(function type() {
  if (!remove) {
    text = str.slice(0, --i);
    if (text === str) return;
  }

  if (!isTag) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }



  setTimeout(type, 520);

}());
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: You `i` goes to negative infinity, that's why this effect shows up twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exit clause is incorrect - you check if *substring of str == str* - which it never will.

You get it twice because of the way `.slice` works with a negative index

- `.slice(0, 8)` -> start to 8th character
- `.slice(0, -2)` -> start to 2 characters from the end

You can change the exit clause from `if (text === str) return` to

```
if (text === "") return;
```

or

```
if (i === 0) return;
```

Depending on when you want it to end - as your exit clause is before the output, this will leave the last character, so instead:

```
if (i<0) return;
```

```js
var str = 'Coming Soon';
var remove = false;
var i = str.length;
var isTag;
var text;

(function type() {
  if (!remove) {
    text = str.slice(0, --i);
    //console.log(i, text)
    if (i < 0) return;
  }

  if (!isTag) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }

  setTimeout(type, 150);

}());
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

However, I expect there's some mix up between `remove` and `!remove` as you have not-remove (ie add) with --i.   So when adding, you do need to check text==str

Answer (score 2):

It's much cleaner to code the logic directly with async/await rather than to fiddle with timeouts:

```js
function delay(time) {
    return new Promise(r =>
        setTimeout(r, time))
}

async function typeAnimation(div, rtl, text, time) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= text.length; i++) {
        div.innerText = text.slice(0, rtl ? -i : +i)
        await delay(time)
    }
}

async function main() {
    let div = document.querySelector('h1')
    await typeAnimation(div, true, 'Coming soon...', 100)
    await typeAnimation(div, false, 'and here it comes!', 100)
}

main()
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, way cleaner then my code.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two functions with a promise

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo')

const initial = "Coming Soon"
const later = "SeaDogs.com.eu.as"

remove(initial).then(() => add(later))

function remove(text) {
  let i = text.length
  return new Promise(r => {
    removeCharacter()

    function removeCharacter() {
      if (i < 0) {
        r()
        return
      }
      const copy = text.slice(0, i)
      demo.textContent = copy

      setTimeout(removeCharacter, 100)
      i -= 1
    }
  })
}

function add(text) {
  let i = 0
  return new Promise(r => {
    removeCharacter()

    function removeCharacter() {
      if (i > text.length) {
        r()
        return
      }
      const copy = text.slice(0, i)
      demo.textContent = copy

      setTimeout(removeCharacter, 100)
      i += 1
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```