# How to make a text animation with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I want to make a couple of texts appear one by one with a javascript interview, i want each word to pop up one after the other and have the texts appear in 4 different lines and would like to know the best way to go about it as a starter with the language. I saw the following code online but would prefer one i can tell what it does clearly (if else statements and the sorts):

```
(function animate() {
  str.length > 0 ? el.innerHTML += str.shift() : clearTimeout(running); 
  let running = setTimeout(animate, 90);
  // let runnin = setTimeout(animate, 90);
})();
```

I tried working with this to have another text with the same animation but can't seem to get the other to come up only when the first array of words have been completed by doing this to a different function, but it didn't work out like I'd hoped

```
(function ani() {
  if(animate()==false){
    str2.length > 0 ? ell.innerHTML += str2.shift() : clearTimeout(runnin); 
    let run = setTimeout(ani, 90);
  }
  
})();
```

Comment: It would be better if you converted your code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Please clarify the question.

Comment: well i have say 2 sentences, i want to apply a text animation to them, and i don't want the second sentence to start until the first is done. both sentences are in 2 different variables, i split the variables and placed them in an array that runs each word as per the function, both of the variables are running simultaneously which isn't what i want

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74667493/5089567

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.